# Android 4.x Fragment not inheriting Activity Lollipop Theme

Tags: android, fragment, material-design

Simple question.

Given AppCompat theme with new MaterialDesign in mind in pre-lollipop device.

Given Activity extending ActionBar activity as it is suggested by Google

Given REAL (PostHoneycomb) Fragment on the Activity

Results are
1. Activity has correctly picked up theme with nice accent colors wherever they are needed

2. Included fragment (throw dynamic transaction adding, not from XML) does not inherit Material Design theme from Activity and has old Honeycomb blue seekbar buttons
3. The same fragment layout design in AndroidStudio shows correct AppCompat theme
4. Eplicit theme enforcing on Fragment onCreateView using ContextWrapper doesn't work either.

p.s. Can't post screenshots as I don't have reputation

Answer (score 0):

This was an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=169760) with AppCompat 22.1.0 - update to a newer version (either 22.1.1 which contains the fix or 22.2.0 - the current latest version).